# none value in php dropdown list

Tags: php, sql

Is there any simple way to add none value in a dropdown list in php?? I tried the below but it doesn't work. It shows all lname values but not the 'None'.
I do not want to enter 1 none value in database and retrieve it. So if it is possible through php itself.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {  
   echo "<option value=None>" . $row['lname'] . "</option> <br>";
 }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the "none"-option above the others.

```
echo '<option value="">None</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{  
   echo '<option value="' . $row['lname'] . '">' . $row['lname'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm after removing quotes inside <option value="">

Comment: Whoops, changed them. Without will also work, but personally I prefer to give all atrributes quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Two things odd here:
- You need quotes around the None in value=None -- 
- a 
 inside of a select options list isn't ever a smart thing to do.